# Unwanted space in inline code with minted in beamer

Tags: beamer, minted

Why is there a space between `\documentclass` and `{article}` in my inline code?

There are no errors in the log.

```
% arara: pdflatex: { shell : yes }
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{minted}
\newminted{latex}{fontsize=\footnotesize}
\newmintinline{latex}{fontsize=\footnotesize}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{An example}
Why is there a spaces between \latexinline{\documentclass} and \latexinline{{article}} in this inline code: \latexinline{\documentclass{article}}?
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

<sup>Disclaimer: I already know the answer, but since it took me an hour to realize it, I thought a Q&A could be useful to future users.</sup>

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `frame` option `[fragile]` is needed.

See Section 12.9 of the [`beamer` documentation](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf).

```
% arara: pdflatex: { shell : yes }
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{minted}
\newminted{latex}{fontsize=\footnotesize}
\newmintinline{latex}{fontsize=\footnotesize}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{An example}
Why is there a spaces between \latexinline{\documentclass} and \latexinline{{article}} in this inline code: \latexinline{\documentclass{article}}?
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]